# Append a prefix to all files recursively with rename

Tags: bash, rename

I am trying to append the prefix *00_* to all my *pdf* files recursively by using:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | rename 's/^/00_/' *
```

However, in this way I am appending a prefix to the path. What is the expression to modify the filename recursively with *rename*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, rename modifies the entire path. The filename can be considered alone by passing the `-d` flag. Also note that the `*` glob will match all files in the current directory, not just the ones you pass to `stdin`. So to prepend `00_` to the filenames, use:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | rename -d 's/^/00_/'
```

You can also add the `-n` flag to do a dry-run where the renames are printed and not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use find and process the results in a while loop:

```
while read fil;
do 
   file=$(basename $fil);                    # Extract the file name from the path
   dir=$(dirname $fil)                       # Extract the directory from the path
   mv -f "$fil" "$dir/00_$file"              # Use file and dir for the move command
done <<< "$(find . -name "*.pdf")"
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain `bash`, without using an external command (but `mv`):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for pathname in **/*.pdf; do
    basename=${pathname##*/}
    dirname=${pathname%"$basename"}
    mv -- "$pathname" "${dirname}00_$basename"
done
```